# Not Authorized to access id on type IFreightDriver

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I have defined a custom Query with its custom response, like this:

```
input ILocations {
  id: String
  address: String
  latitude: String
  longitude: String
  city: String
  state: String
}

type IBox {
  id: ID
  type: String
  depth: Float
  height: Float
  width: Float
}

type ITruck {
  id: ID
  basePrice: Float
  brand: String
  model: String
  yearModel: Int
  axes: Int
  hasGPS: Boolean
  tons: Float
  utilityPercentage: Float
  fuelEfficiency: Float
  fuelType: FuelType
  frontPhoto: String
  sidePhoto: String
  backPhoto: String
  measuresPhoto: String
  truckBoxId: ID
  truckFreightDriverId: ID
  box: IBox
}

type IFreightDriver {
  id: ID
  state: String
  city: String
  truck: ITruck
}

type Query {
  quotations(
    origin: ILocations
    destination: ILocations
    boxType: String
    boxSize: Float
    truckTons: Float
  ): [IFreightDriver]
    @function(name: "quotations-${env}")
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, provider: iam }])
}
```

If I execute this query on the AppSync dashboard:

```
query {
  quotations (
    origin: {
        address: "sdas"
        latitude: "sdas"
        longitude: "dsa"
        city: "Guadalajara",
        state: "Jalisco"
    },
    destination: {
      address: "sdas"
      latitude: "sdas"
      longitude: "dsa"
      city: "Zapopan",
      state: "Jalisco"
    },
    boxType: "Seca (cerrada)",
    boxSize: 64,
    truckTons: 12
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

I get this error about permissions:

```
{
  "data": {
    "quotations": [
      {
        "id": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "quotations",
        0,
        "id"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "Unauthorized",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 20,
          "column": 5,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Not Authorized to access id on type IFreightDriver"
    }
  ]
}
```

But, if I stringify the response from the lambda, and I change the query to receive a String, like this:

```
  quotations(
    origin: ILocations
    destination: ILocations
    boxType: String
    boxSize: Float
    truckTons: Float
  ): String
    @function(name: "quotations-${env}")
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, provider: iam }])
```

I receive the response correctly...

```
{
  "data": {
    "quotations": "[{\"id\":\"19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a\",\"state\":\"Jalisco\",\"city\":\"Zapopan\",\"truck\":{\"__typename\":\"Truck\",\"model\":\"1234\",\"tons\":12,\"yearModel\":2020,\"measuresPhoto\":\"freight-driver/19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a/trucks/qzo1x9g7kvb51.jpg\",\"truckFreightDriverId\":\"19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a\",\"createdAt\":\"2020-08-13T21:02:36.305Z\",\"brand\":\"chevrolet\",\"fuelEfficiency\":12,\"truckBoxId\":\"b3d9000f-0464-4c3d-b436-f380b19d6fd5\",\"backPhoto\":\"freight-driver/19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a/trucks/QCzn1_mWetzZjAFavJYSaug4F2IMAeOAzJa7T6rhC5Q.jpg\",\"frontPhoto\":\"freight-driver/19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a/trucks/dlb0275xqna51.png\",\"utilityPercentage\":12,\"updatedAt\":\"2020-08-13T21:02:36.305Z\",\"sidePhoto\":\"freight-driver/19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a/trucks/ebcpyk19csa51.jpg\",\"fuelType\":\"premium\",\"hasGPS\":true,\"id\":\"b7ec3b05-78c6-4ed9-823d-172a1e9991e5\",\"axes\":12,\"box\":{\"__typename\":\"Box\",\"width\":4,\"height\":4,\"updatedAt\":\"2020-08-13T21:02:35.840Z\",\"depth\":4,\"createdAt\":\"2020-08-13T21:02:35.840Z\",\"id\":\"b3d9000f-0464-4c3d-b436-f380b19d6fd5\",\"type\":\"Seca (cerrada)\"}},\"basePrice\":null}]"
  }
}
```

Why is asking for these permissions? If someone needs the response I'm receiving:

```
[
    {
        "id": "19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a",
        "state": "Jalisco",
        "city": "Zapopan",
        "truck": {
            "__typename": "Truck",
            "model": "1234",
            "tons": 12,
            "yearModel": 2020,
            "measuresPhoto": "freight-driver/19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a/trucks/qzo1x9g7kvb51.jpg",
            "truckFreightDriverId": "19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a",
            "createdAt": "2020-08-13T21:02:36.305Z",
            "brand": "chevrolet",
            "fuelEfficiency": 12,
            "truckBoxId": "b3d9000f-0464-4c3d-b436-f380b19d6fd5",
            "backPhoto": "freight-driver/19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a/trucks/QCzn1_mWetzZjAFavJYSaug4F2IMAeOAzJa7T6rhC5Q.jpg",
            "frontPhoto": "freight-driver/19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a/trucks/dlb0275xqna51.png",
            "utilityPercentage": 12,
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-13T21:02:36.305Z",
            "sidePhoto": "freight-driver/19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a/trucks/ebcpyk19csa51.jpg",
            "fuelType": "premium",
            "hasGPS": true,
            "id": "b7ec3b05-78c6-4ed9-823d-172a1e9991e5",
            "axes": 12,
            "box": {
                "__typename": "Box",
                "width": 4,
                "height": 4,
                "updatedAt": "2020-08-13T21:02:35.840Z",
                "depth": 4,
                "createdAt": "2020-08-13T21:02:35.840Z",
                "id": "b3d9000f-0464-4c3d-b436-f380b19d6fd5",
                "type": "Seca (cerrada)"
            }
        },
        "basePrice": null
    }
]
```

UPDATE: Also I tried to change the lambda response to just return an array of ids, something like this:

response from lambda:
`[ { id: '19847d0c-185c-48f6-9e5c-435e3907133a' } ]`

error from AppSync:

```
{
  "data": {
    "quotations": [
      {
        "id": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "quotations",
        0,
        "id"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "Unauthorized",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 20,
          "column": 5,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Not Authorized to access id on type IFreightDriver"
    }
  ]
}
```

schema.graphql:

```
type IFreightDriver {
  id: ID
}

type Query {
  quotations(
    origin: ILocations
    destination: ILocations
    boxType: String
    boxSize: Float
    truckTons: Float
  ): [IFreightDriver]
    @function(name: "quotations-${env}")
    @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, provider: iam }])
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide permission to access `IFreightDriver`. Since you are setting `auth` for the query but not on the object it is accessing/returning (which in your case is `IFreightDriver`), therefore it is throwing you permission error. However, when you switch your query to return just a string, you do not need to set any permission for that and that's why you don't see any error. Same is the case when you are returning just the `id` of `IFreightDriver`. It won't allow you to access the ids unless you set permission on `IFreightDriver`.

Comment: Yeah! I did not know that just adding @aws_iam to the types... And that's it! God bless you!

Comment: Glad to help you! :) God bless you too!